# Microsoft regular expression pattern failed to match

Tags: c#, regex

I was trying to use my regex with the options: ignore case, multiline, and ignore white space. But it fails to match. Here's the regex:

```
"  
\s+(?(U|US|USD)\s*\$\s([a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)(\s[a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)+)\s+(\-\s(Savings|Chequing|\w+)\s(\d{5})\-(\d{7})\s*){0,1}
(Savings|Chequing|\w+)\s(?\d{5}\-(\d{7}))\s+(Available Balance[:]\s[$](?[0-9.,]{3,20})\sUSD\s
[$](?[0-9,.]{3,20}))
"
```

Here's an example of a string I want to match:

```
"Close Quick Menu Button
                 U$ smith Hi interest2 
Savings 04237-4500385 Available Balance: $0.00 USD 
$0.00 USD 
Open r"
```

I think I made mistake is `(?<availBal>[0-9.,]{3,20})\s` because the expression matches using the preceding part of the expression

I have been trying with different patterns with no avail.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: which language? javascript?

Comment: Microsoft regular expression used in c#. strictly speaking the pattern is is prefixed with @ in the c# program

Comment: How are you specifying options? They're not in the code you posted. Why did you tag this C#? There's no C# posted either. `(?<availBal>[0-9.,]{3,20})\s` is not in your pattern so we have no way of knowing what “the preceding part” is.

Answer (score 1):

The thing I'm noticing is you have `Available Balance` right in the middle of your regex.

You need to change that to `Available\sBalance`. When it says it ignores whitespace, that means whitespace in the regex not the string you match against.

---

This regex works. I changed the `(?` to `(?:` and I added a `+`.

```
\s+(?:(U|US|USD)\s*\$\s([a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)(\s[a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)+)\s+(\-\s(Savings|Chequing|\w+)\s(\d{5})\-(\d{7})\s*){0,1}(Savings|Chequing|\w+)\s(?:\d{5}\-(\d{7}))\s+(Available\sBalance[:]\s[$](?:[0-9.,]{3,20})\sUSD\s+[$](?:[0-9,.]{3,20}))
```

But you're ignoring whitespace, so why not write this legibly? I also changed some unnecessary things you had:

```
\s+(?:(U|US|USD) \s* \$ \s ([a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)
   (\s[a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)+)
\s+(-\s(Savings|Chequing|\w+)
\s (\d{5})-(\d{7})\s*)?
   (Savings|Chequing|\w+)
\s (?:\d{5}-(\d{7}))
\s+(Available \s Balance: \s \$ (?:[0-9.,]{3,20}) \s USD
\s+\$(?:[0-9,.]{3,20}))
```

Comment: thx, after the change I was able to batch up to the part before the last [$]

so the following matches
<pre>
"
\s+(?<desc>(U|US|USD)\s*\$\s([a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)(\s[a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)+)\s+(\-\s(Savings|Chequing|\w+)\s(\d{5})\-(\d{7})\s*){0,1}
(Savings|Chequing|\w+)\s(?<acctNbr>\d{5}\-(\d{7}))\s+(Available\sBalance[:]\s[$](?<availBal>[0-9.,]{3,20})\sUSD\s

"</pre>

Comment: thx, the updated answer does match but, I can't quite extract explicitly by name, balance,,,.

unfortunately I can't get the correct result by ${1}, ${2} ...,for acct name, acct number, and available balance and actual balance with one pass

Comment: @gg89 You should use back ticks (`) around code in comments, otherwise  it may become formatting.

Comment: I think I am close to an answer using same regex options with extract list of ${desc},${acctNbr},${availBal},${bal}

`    \s+(?<desc>(U|US|USD)\s*\$\s([a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)(\s[a-z0-9$,.'_-]+)+)\s+(\-\s(Savings|Chequing|\w+)\s(\d{5})\-(\d{7})\s*){0,1}
    (Savings|Chequing|\w+)\s(?<acctNbr>\d{5}\-(\d{7}))\s+(Available\sBalance\:\s\$(?<availBal>[0-9.,]{3,20})\sUSD\s+)
\$(?<bal>[0-9.,]{3,20})\s`
   when combining that with the ability to match against

`   U$ J. Smith current - Checking 09999-8887777
Checking 09999-8887777 USD $0.00`
    
same extract list fails. looking conditional/look ahead